# Swing frame with a list of checkboxes

Tags: java, swing, list, jcheckbox

I'm a newcomer to Swing and have to create a somewhat complex frame. My MVC application gets recipes from the Internet in the service layer, whereas I need the view layer to allow the user to select the interesting recipes among those obtained, depending on whether each checkbox is selected or not. It should be noted that I've used the page-by-page iterator design pattern to obtain the recipes so the Swing frame should also use pagination (i.e. 10 recipes per page).

Taking all this into consideration, how can I create a frame with two lists (list of recipe names and list of checkboxes) and a convenient layout so that every checkbox is bound to the corresponding recipe name? Of course, data from the recipe list has to be obtained from the proper service method.

Comment: Sounds like a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). For specific guidance, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits any problem you encounter.

Comment: If you show your list vertically the best is `GridBagLayout`, it make the size of grid as per component size